HTC Desire Z boot loop
I put in the battery on my HTC Desire Z, set it on to charge, press the power button, and boom, a loud little boot-up song with the logo on the screen "htc quietly brilliant" not so very quiet. 5 seconds later, it goes dark, and BOOM, right in my face with that same noise and logo. It has been in a loop like that since.
Yes, I'm aware that the HTC Desire Z was released years ago, but I'm still willing to try. I have tried force shutdown and everything that I could find, but first of all, it won't even turn off and it's giving me a migraine headache from that loud noise. I'm out of options, and I'm not risking an electric shock from taking out the battery.

Leave the phone charging for a time without powering it on. Assuming all hardware keys are functional you should be able to enter recovery mode ( recovery hold volume down and power) and perform a factory reset. Smartphone batteries use a voltage of less than 10 Volt. Not sure how anybody could manage getting an electric shock from such a low voltage.
